# How do you make a highlighted outline appear in leaflet.js on mouseover and by hyperlink?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I need to make an outline appear around an object when the user mouses over the object in leaflet. Right now, I can make the object highlighted all the time or not at all. Here is a sample of my code:

```
var polygon1 = L.polygon([
  [83.34425, -19.51172], 
  [83.2571, -15.86426], 
  [83.07408, -16.04004], 
  [82.78192, -17.31445], 
  [82.62569, -11.42578], 
  [82.36164, -11.29395], 
  [82.11236, -12.48047], 
  [82.37332, -22.71973], 
  [82.64822, -22.93945], 
  [83.34425, -19.51172]
], {
  color: 'yellow',
  opacity: 0.0,
  fillColor: '#fff',
  fillOpacity: 0.0
});
polygon1.bindLabel(popup_csb);
polygon1.bindPopup(content_csb);
polygon1.addTo(map);
```

I need to make an event for the object to be outlined in two circumstances.

1. When the mouseover takes place, to show the highlight as well as the popup label. The highlight would then go away when the mouse moves off the object.
2. When the user clicks on a link on the page (a list of buildings) and the object is outlined to show the user where the building is on the map.

The second case would also have to have a disable event when the user clicks another building.

Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you would need to have your default and highlight styles handy:

```
var style = {
    'default': {
        'color': 'yellow'
    },
    'highlight': {
        'color': 'red'
    }
};
```

Create some polygons and group them so they're easily accessible:

```
var group = new L.LayerGroup([
    new L.Polygon([
        [-50, -50], [50, -50], [50, -10], [-50, -10]
    ], {
        'label': 'Polygon 1',
        'popup': 'Polygon 1'
    }),
    new L.Polygon([
        [-50, 10], [50, 10], [50, 50], [-50, 50]
    ], {
        'label': 'Polygon 2',
        'popup': 'Polygon 2'
    })
]).addTo(map);
```

Create a variable to store the highlighted layer and function for setting and unsetting the highlight:

```
// Variable for storing highlighted layer
var highlight;

function setHighlight (layer) {
  // Check if something's highlighted, if so unset highlight
  if (highlight) {
    unsetHighlight(highlight);
  }
  // Set highlight style on layer and store to variable
  layer.setStyle(style.highlight);
  highlight = layer;
}

function unsetHighlight (layer) {
  // Set default style and clear variable
  layer.setStyle(style.default);
  highlight = null;
}
```

Iterate over layers, set style, bind label and popup and add handlers:

```
// Iterate
group.eachLayer(function (layer) {

    // Set default style
    layer.setStyle(style.default);
    // Bind label with polygon option variable
    layer.bindLabel(layer.options.label);
    // Bind popup with polygon option variable
    layer.bindPopup(layer.options.popup);

    // Mouseover handler
    layer.on('mouseover', function (e) {
        // Set highlight
        setHighlight(layer);
    });

    // Mouseout handler
    layer.on('mouseout', function (e) {
         // Unset highlight
        unsetHighlight(layer);
    });

    // Fetch list from DOM
    var list = L.DomUtil.get('list'),
        // Add list item
        item = L.DomUtil.create('li', 'item', list),
        // Add link
        link = L.DomUtil.create('a', 'link', item);

    // Set link text
    link.textContent = layer.options.label;
    // Set link href
    link.href = '#';

    // Add clickhandler to link
    L.DomEvent.addListener(link, 'click', function (e) {
        // Set highlight
        setHighlight(layer);
    });
});
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/LjzFbI?p=preview

Comment: This is AWESOME. You really saved my bacon. Twice, now! Thanks a million. I'll add a follow-up if I have any further questions for this one.

Comment: How does one focus the map on a location? For instance, this code: var map = L.map('map').setView([79,-50], 5); instantiates a map and centers on that location. How do you direct the map to that location on the fly within the context of the above example? Each polygon would need a coordinate position assigned.  Thanks!