# In Leaflet.js, how do you focus the map on a polygon that is being highlighted by external JS?

Tags: jquery, leaflet

How does one focus the map on a location?

My setup is based on this post:
[How do you make a highlighted outline appear in leaflet.js on mouseover and by hyperlink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32971673/how-do-you-make-a-highlighted-outline-appear-in-leaflet-js-on-mouseover-and-by-h)

I have a list of links on the side of the page in a different layer and have set it up to allow the map to highlight a building when the link is clicked, but would also like to move the focus of the map to that building.

So for this code:

```
function setHighlight (layer) {
  // Check if something's highlighted, if so unset highlight
  if (highlight) {
    unsetHighlight(highlight);
  }
  // Set highlight style on layer and store to variable
  layer.setStyle(style.highlight);
  highlight = layer;
}
```

I want to additionally focus on the polygon calling the function. For instance:

```
var group = new L.LayerGroup([
new L.Polygon([
    [-50, -50], [50, -50], [50, -10], [-50, -10]
], {
    'label': 'Polygon 1',
    'popup': 'Polygon 1'
}),
new L.Polygon([
    [-50, 10], [50, 10], [50, 50], [-50, 50]
], {
    'label': 'Polygon 2',
    'popup': 'Polygon 2'
})
]).addTo(map);
```

Is there a definition to add to the polygon to indicate its position? Or is there code that can focus the map on the center of the polygon?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call the `getBounds` method on your `L.Polygon`'s, which will return you a `L.LatLngBounds` object. That object has a `getCenter` method which will return you a `L.LatLng` object which contains the center coordinates of your polygon. You can use that to pan your map using the `panTo` method of `L.Map`. Or you can use the `L.LatLngBounds` object to zoom and pan to the polygon using the `fitBounds` method of `L.Map`:

```
// Have a polygon
var polygon = new L.Polygon(...).addTo(map)

// Get bounds object
var bounds = polygon.getBounds()

// Fit the map to the polygon bounds
map.fitBounds(bounds)

// Or center on the polygon
var center = bounds.getCenter()
map.panTo(center)
```

Using your code that would look something like this:

```
function setHighlight (layer) {
    // Check if something's highlighted, if so unset highlight
    if (highlight) {
        unsetHighlight(highlight);
    }
    // Set highlight style on layer and store to variable
    layer.setStyle(style.highlight);

    // Fit map to layer bounds
    var bounds = layer.getBounds();
    map.fitBounds(bounds);

    highlight = layer;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks again. One quick question - can you show code for displaying the label at the same time the map focuses on the object?